# Library/SDK to transcribe video speech to subtitle file

Tags: open-source, library, video, cloud-service, transcription

I'm looking for a reliable library/SDK/tool/service to transcribe a given `.mp4` video files into timed text (i.e. the speech in the video). Better to be a `.srt` subtitle format. Is there any such tool or library?

Preference is open-source/free software. But good paid service recommendations are also welcome.

Comment: To be sure I understand correctly: Should the tool transcribe the *speech* found in the video? Or the text *displayed* in the video? In any language?

Comment: The speech in a video.